# Deleting previous files when deploying

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core

When I deploy my project to the raspberry, all the files in and folders of  `c$\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\MyPackage` are deleted even if I unchecked `uninstall and re-install my package.All information about the application state is deleted` in my project properties

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to check `keep all files on device - even those that are no longer a part of your layout